# Can't change overlay color and opacity in fancybox 2.1.4

Tags: jquery

This seems so simple. I edited the overlay parameters in the helper file that was included in demo.html but I can't get it to work. I've looked through every .css and .js file as well.

After a week of playing with this, I'm frustrated. As I said, it seems so simple but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

// Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color

```
$(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
    wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
    closeClick : true,

    openEffect : 'none',

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        },
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.55)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: interested as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it via your css:

```
.fancybox-overlay {
  background: #fbe9d5;
}
```